# Browser Not Refreshing Without Rebuilding Project ASP.NET 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I am trying out ASP.NET 5.0 Visual Studio Community 2015.

I have a standard Web Application and just going through the tutorial to get familiar with ASP.NET 5.0

The tutorial states

"Save the file and, without rebuilding the project, refresh your web browser. You should see the updated text. ASP.NET 5 no longer requires that you manually build your server-side logic before viewing it, making small updates much faster to inspect during development."

http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html

I tried it and it is not working for me.  I noticed when I save the file the break points are now disabled.  When I reload the page it does not show the change.  Is there a setting or configuration that I am missing to allow this to happen?

Comment: How are you accessing the site? Are you loading via Visual Studio using debugging or view in browser?

Comment: Perhaps add the link to the tutorial into your question.

Comment: I am loading the site through Visual Studio 2015 using IIS Express and in debug mode.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure you start the project without debugging (Ctrl + F5 in VS instead of F5). The compile on the fly doesn't work with a debugger attached